# Why does the contentSize of my UIScrollView not change?

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

I'm trying to make a `UIScrollView` that contains different settings. Although I connected the UIScrollView to my ViewController and programmatically changed the content size, the `UIScrollView` only scrolls horizontally, which is not the way it is supposed to (it's supposed to only scroll vertically). This is what I use to define the UIScrollView content size :

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 1400)
```

Another important thing is that I set the View controller simulated size to freeform with a width of 375 and an height of 1000.

I've been trying to figure out for a while and I can't find what I'm doing wrong. If you have any idea what could this be due to I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your code so that we can what is wrong.Specially the scrollview initializing and where are you setting the content size.

Comment: Read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: The code for the whole view controller is very long and the only part that is actually related to the UIScrollView is the line I posted above. @Ahmad

Comment: Thanks rob, but so what do you suggest I should do? I actually set all the constraints on my own, so I don't believe the issue is actually autolayout. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: Trying setting the content size in viewdidlayoutsubviews function and let me know if it works or not

Comment: @Ahmad thanks so much, that actually worked. If you want to write it as an answer I can pick it as the correct answer. Do you know why it only works in viewdidlayoutsubviews?

Comment: It's because where you were doing it was too soon. `self.view.bounds.width` didn't have its real value yet.

Comment: @GiulioColleluori The scenario that i faced was when debugging on different screen sizes, the calling of scrollview contentsize in viewdidload setted the wrong content size.Like if the size of view in storyboard is 320 than in viewdidload the size returned by is always 320 even for iphone 6 and 6 plus so setting the content size in viewDidLayoutSubviews() works because the autolayout has finished processing each view and the sizes are good.

Comment: I have not tried it yet but UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width should work good for getting sizes in all scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 1400)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollview contentSize dynamically(depending subviews frame)

Swift:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var contentRect = CGRect.zero

        for view in self.scrollView.subviews {
           contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
        }

        self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
    }
}
```

Objective C:

```
 - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                        CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;

                        for(UIView *view in scrollView.subviews)
                           contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect,view.frame);

                           scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
                       });
}
```